# Closet Wall, is it Load Bearing?

Tags: walls, structural, load-bearing, remodeling

Trying to figure out if the front wall of this pantry cabinet is load bearing. We'd like to remove the front of the pantry and install cabinets here instead of the closet, but unsure if we can pull down the framing around the door. We have photos of the wall when it was just studs and a copy of the original floor plan.

[image: Pantry Closet Door]

[image: Framing of Pantry Closet]

[image: Floor Plan Image]

Comment: Do you have a plan for the floor once the wall is gone?  You'll surely have to chip out the cut tile(s) and replace them, the grout will be tough to match.

Comment: Great question! We actually have some spare tiles that were left in the basement and are in the process of refinishing all the grout to a darker color using one of those "stain and seal" products, so I don't think the flooring will be an issue.

Comment: Your plan suggests there's a triangular void space between the stairs, pantry, and the room on the lower right.  That's nice to have as a cable riser or air duct in the future.

Answer (score 15):

The framing above the pantry door is not load bearing. The doorway to the left of the pantry in the middle picture is load bearing. You can tell by the solid header.

Answer (score 1):

- I'd be amazed if a pantry wall was loadbearing
- There are stairs behind the pantry. The floor joists must end at the stairs, therefore they must be supported by a loadbearing wall. Therefore the back wall of the pantry must be loadbearing. Having another loadbearing wall only 2' away at the front of the pantry would be unlikely

but...

- Your front of pantry wall has a double header. I associate that with structural walls
- Your front of pantry has more verticals than I'd expect for a non-structural wall

I'm not personally convinced either way.

Comment: The funny thing about tiny walls is that they can turn out preposterously beefy for what they do. You always have a king stud and trimmer / jack stud, and you always have a stud at the end of the section you frame. That's all this wall has.

Comment: @Valkor - "You always have a king stud and a jack stud" - not in my house. But from a quick google this does seem like standard practice in the US.